# Trouble with aggregates and grouping in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, aggregate

I'm creating a query that groups status dates of member records on one line in the following format:

```
     MemberID  P1StatusDate   P2StatusDate   P3StatusDate   P4StatusDate
      10        NULL             NULL         NULL           08/20/2017
```

In this particular case the first 3 statuses are null, but they can be populated.
I created this with the following query:

```
    select memberid, max(case when statustype = 'Applicant' then cast(B.statusdate as date)end) as P1StatusDate
    max(case when B.statustype = 'Pending' then cast(B.statusdate as date)end) as P2StatusDate
    max(case when B.statustype = 'In Progess' then cast(sh.statusdate as date)end) as P3StatusDate
    max(case when B.statustype = 'Approved' then cast(B.statusdate as date)end) as P4StatusDate
    from Table A
    inner join B
    on A.statusdate = B.statusdate
    group by memberid
```

The problem I've found is that if a member has 2 Approved records with different dates, only one shows up as P4StatusDate.  For example:

```
    MemberID    Status    StatusDate
     10          Approved    08/19/2017
     10          Approved    08/20/2017
```

This appears as:

```
     MemberID    P1StatusDate  P2StatusDate   P3StatusDate   P4StatusDate
      10          Null          Null             Null          08/20/2017
```

The 08/19/2017 record is omitted.

If I alter the query to include the statusdate in the group by, it will correctly populate both records for this member.

```
    MemberID    P1StatusDate    P2StatusDate   P3StatusDate   P4StatusDate
    10            Null           Null           Null            08/19/2017
    10            Null           Null           Null            08/20/2017
```

However, this will also cause each statusdate record to appear on a different line for other members:

```
    MemberID  P1StatusDate  P2StatusDate   P3StatusDate  P4StatusDate
     15         01/01/2017    NULL           NULL          NULL
     15                       03/01/2017     NULL          NULL
     15          NULL         NULL           04/01/2017    NULL
     15          NULL         NULL           NULL          05/01/2017
```

Is there a way to keep the grouping so that all the status dates are grouped on one line, but also keeps records where there are multiple records with the same status as I indicated above?

Answer (score 0):

aggregate over an aggregated derived table

```
select memberid, max(p1date), max(p2date), max(p3date), max(p4date)
from (
select  ..... -- your raw grouping with nulls 
from table
group by ...
) x
group x.memberid
```

Answer (score 0):

From your SQL query

```
WITH t_status AS
(
SELECT memberid, [status],
       CASE WHEN [status] = 'Applicant' THEN statusdate ELSE NULL END P1StatusDate,
       CASE WHEN [status] = 'Pending' THEN statusdate ELSE NULL END P2StatusDate,
       CASE WHEN [status] = 'In Progress' THEN statusdate ELSE NULL END P3StatusDate,
       CASE WHEN [status] = 'Approved' THEN statusdate ELSE NULL END P4StatusDate,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY memberid, [status] ORDER BY statusdate) rnum
  FROM t_member_status -- your table name
)

SELECT memberid,
       MAX(P1StatusDate) P1StatusDate,
       MAX(P2StatusDate) P2StatusDate,
       MAX(P3StatusDate) P3StatusDate,
       MAX(P4StatusDate) P4StatusDate
  FROM t_status
 GROUP BY memberid, rnum
 ORDER BY memberid, rnum
```

Result (added a sample data memberid 20 to simulate other records with other values of status and with the same status as well for the same memberid)

```
memberid    P1StatusDate    P2StatusDate    P3StatusDate    P4StatusDate
10          NULL            NULL            NULL            2017-08-19
10          NULL            NULL            NULL            2017-08-20
15          2017-01-01      2017-03-01      2017-04-01      2017-05-01
20          2017-01-01      2017-03-01      2017-04-01      2017-05-01
20          NULL            NULL            NULL            2017-05-02
```

Comment: Adding the aggregate query didn't help.  Selecting Max(P4StatusDate) was still eliminating one of the two dates for the same member. To solve this I had to add an extra field for the grouping that further differentiated the two records.

Comment: I edited the query. this may suffice for the sample data you provided

Comment: The CTE does work better, but the results are still a little off.  It gives one row of all NULL, then one row with 2017-08-19 for P4, then another NULL row, and then a row with 2017-08-20.

Comment: on which sample data are you getting that? you have to show us that, we are creating you the solution the best of our knowledge base only on your sample data since we do not have full visibility of your entire database.